# Column does not exist in django 1.6.5

Tags: python, django, database, syncdb

I have an application in Django 1.6.5. I have a model where I removed one field, I added another field, and the third upgraded. And when we now turn to the model in the admin panel, I get the message:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/app/subscription/
column app_subscription.enabled does not exist
```

The command `python manage.py syncdb` does not work.

Comment: @Scironic I get an error: `python manage.py migrate app
The app 'app' does not appear to use migrations.`

Comment: Did you check if there are no references to ```enabled``` field in all files of your project? (especially in ```admin.py```'s).

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy no references

Comment: @mark: migrations are not automagically created.

Comment: Also in strings? (for example, in lists of field names)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers so I must do `python manage.py makemigrations app` then `python manage.py migrate app` then `python manage.py syncdb`?

Comment: @mark: you're using django 1.6, which doesn't have migrations support built in (please refer to the documentation for *your* version of Django, `makemigration` is for django >= 1.7).  You do have a `migrate` command so I assume you have `South` (http://south.aeracode.org/) installed, so your best bet is to read `South`'s documentation, cf my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Django (hopefully) doesn't modify your database schema if you don't *explicitely* ask for it. The `syncdb` command works perfectly, but (as documented) it will only create tables that don't yet exists (and are not marked as being managed externally in your `models`).

So you have mostly three options here:

1. manually drop your table and re-run `syncdb`. This mean you will loose all  our data, so it's hardly a "solution"
2. manually alter your database schema. You won't loose your data, but you'll have to repeat the same (manual) operation everywhere your app is deployed... If it's only installed on your local workstation that might be ok, else it's not a reliable professional production-level option.
3. Use `South` (which seems to be installed since you do have a `migrate` command available.

Note that solution #3 imply that you do create the migration files for your app, as documented here : http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#the-first-migration

Answer (score 0):

It just happened that I faced the same issue with django 1.9.x, where I added a new field in my django app which triggered the same error as you mentioned above. 
I logged into the `dbshell` environment using

```
python manage.p dbshell # I know some use ./manage.py
```

and dropped all of my tables by running the following command within the `dbshell` to drop the tables

```
your_psql=# drop schema public cascade;
```

This will drop all of your tables (be careful as you may lose your data, there away to keep the data!) and you will get a message right after executing this command tells you that all dropped. Right after that run the following command to create the schema again, otherwise your server will not run:

```
your_psql=# create schema public;
```

Then just do the

```
python manage.py makemigrations # you might not need this, and 
python manage.py migrate
```

And you're ready to go.

I know this answer might be very late but I hope it will help someone.

Cheers